# ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?: ENOENT: no such file or directory node_modules/node-sass/vendor

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I was trying to run an angular project in windows 10. It is the same project that I am doing in Ubuntu. When I clone the repository and install all the node packages I encountered this error.

> ERROR in
> ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/scss/style.scss
> Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir
> 'C:\Users\me\Documents\ad-fingerprinting\web\node_modules\node-sass\vendor'
> at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:911:18)
> at Object.getInstalledBinaries (C:\Users\me\Documents\ad-fingerprinting\web\node_modules\node-sass\lib\extensions.js:124:13)
> at foundBinariesList (C:\Users\me\Documents\ad-fingerprinting\web\node_modules\node-sass\lib\errors.js:20:15)
> at foundBinaries (C:\Users\me\Documents\ad-fingerprinting\web\node_modules\node-sass\lib\errors.js:15:5)
> at Object.module.exports.missingBinary (C:\Users\me\Documents\ad-fingerprinting\web\node_modules\node-sass\lib\errors.js:45:5)
> at module.exports (C:\Users\me\Documents\ad-fingerprinting\web\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:15:30)
> at Object. (C:\Users\me\Documents\ad-fingerprinting\web\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
> at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
> at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
> at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
> at Object. (C:\Users\me\Documents\ad-fingerprinting\web\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:3:14)
> at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)  @ ./src/scss/style.scss 4:14-195  @ multi ./src/scss/style.scss

**node -v 8.5.0**

**Angular CLI version 1.4.3**

Comment: are you using sass ?

Comment: yes I am using material sass

Comment: Update node to latest version!

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Try this

`npm install node-sass`

Then

`npm run start`

Comment: @FadiAboMsalam it worked for me too. Could you explain us a little bit about the answer.

Comment: holy sith. i was at the verge of giving up after a Vue project i had abandoned not so long ago was giving me tons of errors!! and this just saved me. autoupvote

Comment: This failed for me, but I ran the npm install again, it started to work!

Comment: Can anybody provide a YouTube link for npm basics?  Where do I start?

Comment: @Moojjoo checkout this its helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2V1UUhBJ62Y

Comment: without installing npm install node-sass we can use this command                          
 npm rebuild   node-sass

Comment: This is helpful for me. `'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 21):

Run this command:

```
npm install --save node-sass
```

This does the same as above. Similarly to the answer above.

Answer (score 14):

I am also facing the same problem, but I resolve.

```
npm install node-sass
```

Above command work for me. As per your synario you can use the blow command.

**Try 1**

```
 npm install node-sass
```

**Try 2**

Remove the `node_modules` folder and run:

```
npm install
```

**Try 3**

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

**Try 4**

```
npm install --save node-sass
```

For your ref you can go through this [github link](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/530)

Answer (score 3):

I tried both

`npm rebuild node-sass`

and

`npm install --save node-sass`

Later by seeing EACCESS, i checked the folder permission of /node_modules, which was not 777 permission

Then I gave

`chmod -R 777 *`

-R for recursively(setting the same permission not in the dir but also inside nested sub dir)

- is for all files in current directory

**What is file permission**

To check for permission you can use

```
ls -l
```

If u don't know about it, first see here, then check the [url](https://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/)

Every file and directory has permission of 'rwx'(read, write, execute). and if 'x' permission is not there, then you can not execute, if no 'w', you can not write into the file. if something is missing it will show in place of r/w/x with '-'. So, if 'x' permission is not there, it will show like 'rw-'

And there will be 3 categories of user Owner(who created the file/directory), Group(some people who share the same permission and user privilege), Others(general public)

So 1st letter is 'd'(if it is a directory) or '-'(if it is not a directory), followed by rwx for owner, followed by for group, followed by other

```
drwxrwxrwx
```

For example, for 'node_modules'directory I want to give permission to the owner all permission and for rest only read, then it will be

```
drwxr--r--
```

And about the number assume for 'r/w/x' it is **1** and for '-' it is **0**, 777, first 7 is for the owner, followed by the group, followed by other

Let's assume the permission is **rwxr-xrw-**

Now 'rwx' is like '111' and its equivalent decimal is 1*2^2+1*2^1+1*2^0=7

Now 'r-x' is like '101' and its equivalent decimal is 1*2^2+0*2^1+1*2^0=5

Now 'rw-' is like '110' and its equivalent decimal is 1*2^2+1*2^1+0*2^0=6

So, it will be 756

Comment: better to explain , then to add a  link to different site ( which may delete later  and thus become of no use if this answer got more  upvotes)

Comment: Got it Prashant

Answer (score 2):

Laravel Mix 4 switches from node-sass to dart-sass (which may not compile as you would expect, OR you have to deal with the issues one by one)

OR

```
npm install node-sass


mix.sass('resources/sass/app.sass', 'public/css', {
implementation: require('node-sass')
});
```

https://laravel-mix.com/docs/4.0/upgrade

Answer (score 2):

re-install node-sass with version based on your error message

npm install node-sass@v4

Answer (score 1):

Try to run

`npm i node-sass@latest`

Comment: How is this different from other answers?

Comment: This question is almost 2 years old, with an accepted answer and the provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24076044).

Answer (score 0):

you have to update your node.js and angular/cli.If you update these two things then your project has angular.json file instead of angular-cli.json file.Then add css file into angular.json file.If you add css file into angular-cli.json file instead of angular.json file,then errors are occured.

Answer (score 0):

My case:

Missing node-sass in package.json

Solution:

1. npm i --save node-sass@latest
2. remove node-modules folder
3. npm i
4. check "@angular-devkit/build-angular": **"^0.901.0"** version in package.json

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**
goto `/node_modules/node-sass` folder

**Step 2:**
run `yarn install` or `npm install`

If it complains about version incompatibility,
try installing older node-sass versions

And repeat **Step 1, Step 2**

OR you can add this script in the package.json

```
"postinstall": "node ./node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

To be clear node-sass is depracated and must be uninstalled and then a new version of sass must be install.

Do the follow:

1st) try uninstalling it by using this command

`npm uninstall node-sass`

and then 2nd) try installing sass

`npm install --save-dev sass`

this worked for me when I was having issues installing sass on a project using create react app

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in your package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "sass": "^1.49.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
rm -r ./node_modules
npm cache clean --force
npm rebuild node-sass
npm i
npm start
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.