# I am getting a compile error with css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory" using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using [react-responsive-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel) to build out a carousel on a react site. I installed the package with yarn add and got everything working nicely. I then copied and pasted the .scss files from the project git repo into my own project to use as a base (same class names etc) for styling it my own way. Then my project started throwing errors. Specifically this:

./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mysite/node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js'

I have since deleted the .scss files since it was with that change that the error appeared, this did nothing, oddly. I have also tried manually installing css-loader and babel-core as suggested on similar problems, but this did nothing and css-loader still doesn't show up in my node-modules folder.

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "mysite",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.3",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.3",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.15",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "css-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "graphql": "^14.4.2",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-apollo": "^2.5.8",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-lightbox-component": "^1.2.1",
    "react-markdown": "^4.1.0",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.1.49",
    "react-router": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

any ideas what could be going wrong here? I used create-react-app to start the project, do I need to eject it and edit some webpack config file maybe?

It's really weird since the issue started when I added new .scss files, which I since deleted but this didn't revert the issue.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using LINUX OS ? I think that ubuntu internally stores cache for npm modules which in turn are dependencies of our project

Comment: I am on macOS Mojave 10.14.5

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419024/error-in-node-modules-css-loader

Comment: Once remove node modules and package-lock file and then run `npm install` again

Comment: deleting node modules and another yarn install worked... how bizarre. Im sure I tried that earlier too, to no avail. Anyways i'll keep this here for anyone else facing the same problem.

Comment: That's great. Yeah keep on.